# Using the word permeate

Tags: tenses

Does 'The two movies permeate pop culture' make sense or should it be 'have permeated pop culture'?

Comment: Grammatically, they're both fine. Semantically, however, they seem strange. Movies do not generally _permeate_ anything, it sounds odd. You could say that a culture of unhealthy idol worship permeates pop culture, but a movie is too concrete a thing to permeate anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suspect what you are actually trying to say is that the two movies have had a wide-reaching impact on pop culture as a whole, but in both cases this does not quite carry through.

As you can see from Noah's answer, the phrase actually implies that pop culture is the operative thing being spread about/having been spread about.

If you want to say that the movies are a part of pop culture, you could try the following phrase:

"The two movies have permeated **into** pop culture".

Answer (score 1):

They mean two different things and both would make sense in their own context. The first uses the simple present and the second the present perfect. The first would mean that in general the two movies spread pop culture and the second would mean that the two movies *have* spread pop culture.